# Lightweight integration of MySQL into a C++ Project

Tags: c++, mysql

I am working on a cross platform that needs to use a database to store information. I was thinking because MySQL is opensource, would it be possible to remove the networking components from MySQL so that the program can directly interact with it. Is this possible, or should i just ship the install with a copy of mysql server with all the settings predefined and use a connector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite has what you need. http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: nice, just trying it out with http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CppSQLite.aspx, works really nicely, cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think in theory you could do that, but I'm not sure if the amount of work would be worth it and the chances of breaking something would be pretty high. I would just ship mySQL with your application.

Or use sqllite as suggested by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible, but I am not sure it is worth it (or else, use something like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or even [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)).

MySQL is quite robust (thousands of developers, millions of users) so in practice you should consider it won't crash.

Your own application might be less robust. It probably would crash. Then having MySQL still running ensures you that the data are in a sane state.

And you might perhaps be later interested in having some other (perhaps external) application doing SQL requests to your MySQL database, or give the ability to have the MySQL database on a remote server.